# Controlling the stepper motor speed with potentiometer

Tags: arduino, stepper

I'm trying to build a small rotating table with variable speed with EasyDriver, NEMA17 stepper motor, potentiometer, and arduino. I am having some trouble with the code. Basically, the motor rotates the same speed no mather of the potentiometer position. Also the motor starts to rotate when I put my potentiometer near the end position. And rotates constantly only in that position.

I have checked all the hardware components and they are working fine. I guess the problem is in the code. Putting an LED diode on the step pin I see that arduino is working fine, but stepper motor does not move accordingly.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  //STEP PIN
  pinMode (13, OUTPUT);

  //POTPIN
  pinMode (A5, INPUT);

  //DIRPIN
  pinMode (12, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite (12, LOW); 
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  int potValue =  analogRead (A5) / 8;

  digitalWrite (13, HIGH);

  delay (potValue);

  digitalWrite (13, LOW);

  delay (potValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is using the `delay()` function with wrong range of values for this type of motor driver.

Your delay represents the time to make a step, and your rotor speed depends on how many steps has your motor. I recommend playing with delays [**between 10 and 2000**](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-to-control-stepper-motor-with-a4988-driver-and-arduino/) microsseconds to begin with. Your current delay function is being set **between 0 and 128 milliseconds**, which is a lot slower than your motor's requirements.

To solve this problem, try using the [`map()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/) to correctly set up the delay for your motor. I also recommend, instead of `delay()`, use `delayMicroseconds()` function.

Basicaly, you can transform your potentiometer values to a correct delay value using:

```
int delayValue= map(potValue, 0, 1023, 10, 2000);
```

Your code will be something like the code below:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode (13, OUTPUT); //STEP PIN
  pinMode (A5, INPUT); //POTPIN
  pinMode (12, OUTPUT); //DIRPIN
  digitalWrite (12, LOW); 
}

void loop() {
  int potValue =  analogRead (A5); // Read from potentiometer
  int delayValue= map(potValue, 0, 1023, 10,2000); // Map potentiometer value to a value from 300 to 4000

  digitalWrite (13, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(delayValue);
  digitalWrite (13, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(delayValue);
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the reply, I have tried your code and the motor is acting pretty much the same. It moves only when the potentiometer is close to 0. With this code it also doesent move fluently. It has irregular motion.

Comment: Did you try changing the range values from `map()` function? Try doing some tests, maybe `map(potValue, 0, 1023, 10,500);`

Comment: It works better and more fluently when I put "map(potValue, 0, 1023, 10,100)". I still cant seem to get it to rotate slower. If I put upper map value more then 100 it starts to tremble and work irregularly. I want to make it rotate realy slow.

Comment: Theoretically, higher your delay time, slower will be your motor. If it isn't acting accordingly it might be a hardware limitation. Usually motor are built for specifics application in terms of coil resistance, operating voltage e max current, so you have motors suitable for higher speeds (and low torques) or higher torques (and low speed). If you still need to use this motor, did you consider using a gear box?

Comment: Thank you. I have regulated the voltage on the EasyDriver and it works ok right now. Best regards.

Comment: Awesome. If my answer helped you solve your problem, would you mind accepting it as response (green button) ? It would help me a lot :)